# Drupal module to hide part of body field initially

Tags: 7

I'm having trouble finding results for this because there are so many conflicting search terms.

I have a content type in which I want to hide most of the Body to start, but add a Read More type of link which would just use javascript to reveal the rest of the body.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about (I'm converting this site to drupal):

http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/app-10biiFinancialCalculator-iOS.php

I'm having trouble searching for something because "Read More" returns a ton of results about the standard Read More link.

Do you know of a module that will let me do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a jQuery plugin. [See this drupal/stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103657/expandable-content-in-the-drupal-node-page-javascript-functionality).

The [jquery project page for readmore](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/readmore). Other jquery modules can do this as well such as [Expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/). Expander looks newer and more supported (off hand).

You could just add this file to your site's theme folder and theme info file. You probably want to not use `Teasers` anywhere and just rely on the JS readmore links for a [CSS selector targeting your node body](http://drupal.org/node/388372) content. Your theme may have a more specific selector.